# Deploy Webparts Using Script

Tags: web-parts, sharepoint-2013

We have custom web parts developed by a developer and deployed to customer sites (dedicated site collections) using a solution. Problem is, when we update a web part, the changes don't take effect in existing customer sites (or at least that is my theory). I'm guessing I have to copy the latest version of the web part to each site collection. 1) Let me know if my theory is correct 2) Is there a way I can do this via scripting?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the web part was originally and solely deployed as part of a farm solution, then you should be seeing your changes when the solution package is upgraded on the customer sites.

If you have access to Central Administration, I would check the details of your solution in System Settings > Manage farm solutions. Make sure:

- there were no errors
- the appropriate servers are included in Last Operation Details
- Last Operation Time is greater than the date of the solution package

In addition, on the customer site, check Site Settings > Web Designer Galleries > Web parts. Make sure your web part is listed once and the Modified date is greater than the date of the solution package.

Comment: Central Admin looks good. The modified dates are different between my old sites and my new site (with up to date web parts). So now I'm guessing I have to import/overwrite the web parts that are outdated?

Comment: How are you redeploying the solution package? If you are using a combination of retract-remove-add-deploy, try update-spsolution instead. If that doesn't work and is possible, try reactivating the feature on the old sites. For more information, see [this question](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/37179/adding-new-webparts-to-an-already-deployed-solution) on SharePoint StackExchange.

Comment: You know, I'm not actually sure the web part is my problem now as my list is empty. For some reason, when my developer redeploys the project one list is empty, but it's only empty for existing sites not for new sites.

Answer (score 0):

1. We deploy the web part with VS to a folder
2. Deploy solution to production site using stsadm.exe (retract, deploy and upgrade if it exists).
3. IISRESET